# Non Brute Force Advice Solution to Searching String for Words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if you can advise on an algorithm for a non-brute-force solution for iterating through a string, splitting it into two halves, and checking if both halves exist in a dictionary/hash?

For instance, the string "peanutbutter" being split into "peanut" and "butter" (yes, there are other words in there, but for example purposes we can go with those two)

Here's the brute force solution I've come up with for reference:

```
def break_into_spaces(S):
    i = 1
    while i < len(S):
        left = S[i:]
        right = S[:i]
        if left in DICTIONARY and right in DICTIONARY:
            print("Found them!")
        print("{} {}".format(right, left))
        i += 1


break_into_spaces("peanutbutter")
```

Comment: Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: Side comment: use a `for` loop instead of `while` in such a case.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut why do you say `for` instead of `while`? Thanks!

Comment: @iGian the example is below (e.g. "peanutbutter") in the function call. Thanks!

Comment: @ikebukuru You are doing a `while` loop that starts from a value and increment in each loop until it reaches the last value. That's exactly what a `for` loop does, without the need to take care of the increment. It would improve readability of your code.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut so you think `for i in range(1, len(S))`?

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent to your while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My option:

```
wordlist = ['air', 'pack', 'port', 'hard', 'back', 'bag', 'disk', 'ground', 'play']
word = 'playground'

lenw, minlen = len(word), min([len(w) for w in wordlist])
pairs = [(word[:n], word[n:]) for n in range(1,lenw) if (n >= minlen and n < lenw-minlen+1) ]
found = False
for w1, w2 in pairs:
  if w1 in wordlist and w2 in wordlist:
    print('Found ' + word + ' as: ' + w1 + ' + ' + w2)
    found = True
    break
if not found: print('No words found')

#=> Found playground as: play + ground
```

`pairs` is the map of the word split in two, where the two sub-words are no smaller than the smallest word in wordlist. This reduces the number of lookups.

Printing it to see:

```
print(pairs)
#=> [('pla', 'yground'), ('play', 'ground'), ('playg', 'round'), ('playgr', 'ound'), ('playgro', 'und')]
```

---

**I case of large list of words** I'd suggest to group by starting letter (as a vocabulary) then look only for the words inside the intersection between word letters and starting word sets. Here not complete code:

```
letters = set(word)
print(letters) #=> {'r', 'a', 'u', 'g', 'l', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'y', 'p'}

alphabet = {}
for word in wordlist:
    alphabet.setdefault(word[0], set()).add(word)
print(alphabet)
#=> {'a': {'air'}, 'p': {'port', 'play', 'pack'}, 'h': {'hard'}, 'b': {'back', 'bag'}, 'd': {'disk'}, 'g': {'ground'}}
```

So the intersection is: `{'g', 'p', 'd', 'a'}`
Then build the lookup list:

```
lookuplist = []
for i in intersection:
  for word in alphabet[i]:
    lookuplist.append(word)
lookuplist #=> ['air', 'disk', 'ground', 'port', 'pack', 'play']
```

So use `lookuplist` instead of `wordlist`

---

## Making order in the drawer with some methods

```
def vocabulary(wordlist):
  res = {}
  for word in wordlist:
    res.setdefault(word[0], set()).add(word)
  return res

def lookuplist(vocabulary, word):
  vocabulary_alphabet = set(vocabulary.keys())
  word_letters = set(word)
  intersection = vocabulary_alphabet.intersection(word_letters)
  lookuplist = []
  for i in intersection:
    for word in vocabulary[i]:
      lookuplist.append(word)
  return lookuplist

def find_word(word, lookuplist):
  lenw, minlen = len(word), min([len(w) for w in lookuplist])
  pairs = [(word[:n], word[n:]) for n in range(1,lenw) if (n >= minlen and n < lenw-minlen+1) ]
  for w1, w2 in pairs:
    if w1 in lookuplist and w2 in lookuplist: return (word, w1, w2)
  return []
```

That you can use as follow:

```
wordlist = ['air', 'pack', 'port', 'hard', 'back', 'bag', 'disk', 'ground', 'play']
word = 'playground'

vocabulary = vocabulary(wordlist) # run once then store the result
lookuplist = lookuplist(vocabulary, word)
found_word = find_word(word, lookuplist)
print(found_word)
#=> ('playground', 'play', 'ground')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but a good idea could be to store the words in dictionary where the keys are the lengths of the words and the values are set of words, for example. Then create a list of the lengths to iterate over it, instead of iterating over the input word (`s`), for example:

```
words = ['toothpaste',
         'hard-to-find',
         'economic',
         'point',
         'food',
         'seal',
         'outrageous',
         'motionless',
         'ice',
         'tow',
         'boot',
         'cruel',
         'peanut',
         'butter']

index = {}
for word in words:
    index.setdefault(len(word), set()).add(word)

lengths = sorted(index)

def break_into_spaces(s):
    s_length = len(s)
    for length in lengths:
        if length < s_length:
            left = s[length:]
            right = s[:length]

            if left in index[length] and s_length - length in index and right in index[s_length - length]:
                print("{} {}".format(right, left))
                print("Found them!")
        else:
            break


break_into_spaces('peanutbutter')
```

**Output**

```
peanut butter
Found them!
```

So have does this saves time:

1. It avoids you iterate over the whole input word, imagine the case where the input word is shorter than all the words in the dictionary, this will immediately break the loop and print nothing.
2. By storing the words in sets of the same length you only need to check whether there is a matching word of the same length instead of checking against all words. Note that this could be meaningless because dictionary are hash tables, so in theory checking for containment is `O(1)`.

Comment: Cool and interesting way of thinking about the problem!